# Ошибка "...table2excel is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, расширения

Пишу расширение для себя, которое конвертирует table на активной странице вкладки браузера в excel файл и сохраняет. Использую библиотеку table2excel.( https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/find/master?q=). Так как это мое расширение, инжектю последовательно на страницу jquery.js, table2excel.js и файл с вызовом функций конвертирования и сохранения - functin.js
Инжектится все хорошо. Но стоит мне попытаться вызвать функцию - получаю ошибку из заголовка.
Вызывают так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var httl = document.body.innerHTML;
var regex = /[3]+[0-9]{5}/g;
var set = new Set();
httl.match(regex).forEach(v=>set.add(v));
var ltog = Array.from(set);
var sbort = ltog[0];     


$("#spis_k").click(function(){
console.log("Типо сработал клик");
$(".Ymb").table2excel({
exclude: ".noExl",
name: "Excel Document Name",
filename: "Таблица № " + sbort+"от "+ new Date(),
fileext: ".xls",
exclude_img: true,
exclude_links: true,
exclude_inputs: true
});
});
```

Если подключать table2excel, как обычно - через

```
<script src='.../table2excel.js'>
```

в header то все работает. Но так как это у меня расширение, то так подключить нельзя. В итоге у меня грузится в теги

```
<script></script>
```

содержимое table2excel. js и функция не вызывается.
Извините, если это кажется простым и дебильным, но я никак не могу правильно обратится к table2excel

Comment: Забыли скобку { в начале файла где функция ready

Comment: Пишу с телефона, мог пропустить.

Comment: ; пропущена в конце

Comment: Это все опечатки, при создании темы. К сожалению на результат они не влияют.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл глупое решение. Заменить в библиотеке table2excel.js

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
```

На

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Тогда обращение к библиотеки происходит корректное. Как я понимаю все дело в области видимости( доступа)